# Unity Firebase transaction error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database and I have a weird error with transactions. Basically I have a key called "users" with a parameter count and an userlist like this:

```
"users" : {
  "count" : 1,
  "userList" : {
    "LBBgLkOp3bWbZeSfnKVsqkHeW8s1" : true
  }
}
```

I use a transaction to increment the count and add the current user's id to the userList. The problem is that if there isn't a users key (the first time) the transaction completes succesfully but if there is already an users key the transaction fails for no reason...

My code is this

```
 void AddUserAndIncrementCount()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users")
        .RunTransaction(usersData =>
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> users = usersData.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;
            if (users == null)
            { // firstTime
                users = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                users.Add("count", 1);
                users.Add("userList", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { auth.CurrentUser.UserId, true }});
            }
            else
            {
                /* printing users returns this
                    {"count":1,"userList":{"LBBgLkOp3bWbZeSfnKVsqkHeW8s1":true}}
                */
                // INCREMENT COUNT
                users["count"] = int.Parse(users["count"].ToString()) + 1;
                // ADD USER TO LIST
                Dictionary<string, object> userList = users["userList"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
                userList.Add(auth.CurrentUser.UserId, true);
                users["userList"] = userList;
            }
            // END TRANSACTION
            /* printing users returns this now
                {"count":2,"userList":{"LBBgLkOp3bWbZeSfnKVsqkHeW8s1":true,"AM2vI8K106XghEgEgRSkCIpJn0w2":true}}
            */
            usersData.Value = users;
            return TransactionResult.Success(usersData);
        }).ContinueWith(OnAddUserIncrementCountTask);
}

void OnAddUserIncrementCountTask(Task<DataSnapshot> task)
{
    if (task.IsCompleted && !task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
    {
       //Success
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(task.IsFaulted+" - "+task.Exception.Message);
        // True - Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.
    }
}
```

As you can see I printed what I was receiving and sending in the transaction and everything seems fine. I tried to set rules to public (read true and write true) and it also failed, so I don't know if I am doing something bad or if there is something wrong with transactions. The things that bothers me is that if the users key doesn't exist in the database then it doesn't fail so I think it is failing for some strange reason I can't see...

I am testing on an Android device.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was causing the transaction to fail.

It seems there is a bug that makes transactions fail if one of the existing children of the node, or the children of the children, or the value of the node itself is a boolean (`true`, `false`).

To solve it I just replaced the `true` boolean for a `"true"` string and now all transactions work.

So in my above code I replaced (this appears twice in the code)

```
auth.CurrentUser.UserId, true
```

for:

```
auth.CurrentUser.UserId, "true"
```

Hope this post saves some time to the next one running to this bug.

Comment: Firebase developer here.  Thanks for finding a workaround Juan and I apologize for the issue.  this will be fixed in our next SDK release 1.1.3.

Comment: Hello, no problem, I reported this a week ago to your support team, It's not a big problem for me but it was difficult to understand why it was failing. Firebase is awesome! Keep the good work :)